# PHP (or MySQL) crash when retrieving a big database record (~5MB)

Tags: php, memory, pdo, mysqli

It doesnt display any errors, just a blank page. I tried die('test') before I call my function to retrieve a record and it does it, but when I place die('test') after my retrieve row function all I get is an empty page `(on chrome it says this: Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.)`

.. I have tried (with 128M, -1, 64M, etc)

```
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
```

With no luck. I am using mysqli to retrieve the record and a simple query like 'Select data from tblBackup' (only 1 record in the database)

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Update:
I tailed the apache error log and I get this when trying to load the page,

```
[Thu Jun 30 13:47:37 2011] [notice] child pid 25405 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Comment: Look for mysql and web server log, enable error reporting and error logging from php.ini. Also note that, you cannot set memory_limit on runtime.

Comment: @eyazici memory_limit can be changed at runtime `PHP_INI_ALL`

Comment: Ok, MySQL server log shows no errors, but i tailed the apache log and i got this error
@eyazici 
    [Thu Jun 30 13:47:37 2011] [notice] child pid 25405 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Answer (score 2):

Checkout php.ini variables for execution time. Sounds like PHP might be timing out.

```
max_execution_time =3000
max_input_time = 6000
```

Also, you may have this done at the .ini level, but you can add this to get the PHP error. Put these at the top of your file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: Still the same thing... I doubt its the time limit because the blank page appears instantly, not after waiting for 30 seconds or so.

Answer (score 1):

What's the client and server settings for [`max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html)? If it's smaller than than the ~5MB blob you're trying to send across, then the connection will be killed.

Comment: MySQLd  was 16MB, I changed it to 32MB. Still nothing. How would I change the max packet of mysql on php?

Comment: max_packet is for the mysql client<->server communications. PHP doesn't really have anything to do with it, as PHP's just talking to the mysql api library, which then does the connection stuff.

Comment: So, the mysql api (pdo_mysql i presume) has no max packet limit?

Comment: I don't think it's something that could be changed on the fly, but you can always try.

Answer (score 0):

Well, been there man. But at the end of the day: Is that a good way, to handle the query? If you have many results, then LIMIT them down.. maybe with pagination?

Because yes, you can set the limits higher, but in a longer run.. is it really the most effective way?

Comment: I only have one record in the table, no need for pagination.

Comment: Then it must be some cache or something? Why else is it so large?

Answer (score 0):

While compiling php, my --with-pdo-mysql=[DIR] flag seemed to cause the issue. I removed the [DIR] and left it blank. The problem is gone.