# Segmentation Fault When Using MySQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel

I've just started working on a new site in Laravel, and I'm having trouble with the connection to a MYSQL (version 5.5.25a) database. The mysql server is on the same local network, but on a different machine to the web server (OSX server). This set up has been working fine for me in Codeigniter, YII, straight up PHP, etc, for a long time.

I've set up Laravel's `/config/database.php` with my database credentials, however the site times out whenever its on a page that makes a database connection using Laravel's PDO database classes. It gives me the dreaded `Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.` error in chrome.

If i enter the credentials incorrectly (wrong password/username/dbname), Laravel gives me a real MYSQL error message `SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user...`, so it seems like it can communicate the server fine.

If I do a quick and dirty database call using `mysqli` and log the result with chromePHP, everything appears to work fine, and it returns the correct number of rows from the database, no timing out, no problems.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('192.168.1.178', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');

if ($mysqli->connect_error){
    die ("Connect error: " . $mysqli->connect_error );
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username FROM user LIMIT 10")) {
    ChromePhp::log($result->num_rows);
    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}
```

**UPDATE**

I checked the logs, and I get nothing from mysql, but the apache logs show the following error when it times out:

```
child pid 60418 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

I've also noticed that phpinfo() shows that the PDO Client API version is set to `mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 300533` , I wonder if this mismatch between the Client version and the MYSQL server version could be causing a problem?

Why could php/mysql be timing out when I try to use PDO with mysql?

Comment: Seems I'm not the only one with this problem, and it could be specific to the apple setup I am using. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2141886?threadID=2141886&tstart=0

Comment: `phpinfo()` on the web server shows that the PDO Client API version is set to `mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 300533`, I wonder if this could be causing a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 environments CLI & browser. Both should work with your ip or "localhost" but in my experience one environment works with your IP in the DB configuration and the other works with "localhost" in the DB configuration.

Comment: My site is on a virtual domain, so I connect to it via `http://some-made-up-address.dev` through my browser. As you can see above, I connect to the database via IP address, as it is not within the scope of localhost. This set up hasn't caused me any problems in other frameworks. If I enter the same credentials into a codeigniter  or yii set up, it connects to the database fine.

Comment: Might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538484/php-or-mysql-crash-when-retrieving-a-big-database-record-5mb (Laravel is using PDO MySQL).

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with this error while trying out the Laravel 4 beta. I'd see the `Segmentation fault: 11` when running migrations from the command line.

Turns out, my issue was a side-effect of having **MAMP** installed. The version of php **MAMP** provides only runs in browsers. Out of the box, OS X comes with it's own version of php. This is the version OS X will run when you use `php` in the command line.

A quick fix is to add the MAMP php directory to your .profile or .bash_profile files. There's a better guide on how to do this [here](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/getting-command-line-access-php-and-mysql-running-mamp-osx).